# Looping option selection in python

Tags: python, loops

I bought a TI-84 Plus CE with python support and thought I'd have a play at trying to learn python to make cheat sheets etc.

Any way I have this code so far, what I'm struggling to understand is how to loop it so I can keep entering a selection instead of it just running and exiting.

Would appreciate any advice etc
I have tried to look at other posts but I think it's just confusing me more.

Here is the code I have so far...

`

```
def Kilo():
    print("1 000 | 10^3  |  k")
def Mega():
    print("1 000 000  |  10^6  | M")
def Giga():
    print("1 000 000 000  |  10^9  | G")
def Tera():
    print("1 000 000 000 000  |  10^12  | T")
def Peta():
    print("1 000 000 000 000 000  |  10^15  | P")
def Exo():
    print("1 000 000 000 000 000 000  |  10^18  | E")
def milli():
    print(".001  |  10^-3  | m")
def micro():
    print(".000 001  |  10^-6  | u")
def nano():
    print(".000 000 001  | 10^-9  |  n")
def pico():
    print(".000 000 000 001  |  10^-12  | p")
def femto():
    print(".000 000 000 000 001  |  10^-15  | f")
def atto():
    print(".000 000 000 000 000 000 001  |  10^-18  | a")
def invalid_opt():
    print("Invalid choice")
def Exit():
    exit()

options = {"1":["K Kilo",Kilo], "2":["M Mega",Mega], "3":["G Giga",Giga], "4":["T Tera",Tera], "5":["P Peta",Peta], "6":["E Exo",Exo], "7":["m Milli",milli], "8":["u micro",micro], "9":["n nano",nano], "10":["p pico",pico], "11":["f femto",femto], "12":["a atto",atto], "99":["Exit",exit]}

for option in options:
    print(option+") "+options.get(option)[0])
  
choice = input("Please select: ")
 
val = options.get(choice)
if val is not None:
    action = val[1]
else:
    action = invalid_opt

action()
```

`

Comment: Put the code you want to repeat inside a `while True:` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to have an infinite loop. It can be achieved by `while True`:

```
while(True):
    choice = input("Please select: ")
     
    val = options.get(choice)
    if val is not None:
        action = val[1]
    else:
        action = invalid_opt

    action()
```

also, I tink it's not efficient to define a lot of functions to do this.

Comment: ok thanks, i didnt think it looked like the best way to go, what would you recommend?